# MobileFirst connectivity issue with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

While calling simple select statement from `Mobilfirst 7.1 SQL Adapter` to get data data from a SQL Server 2016 table, I get this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.java.lang.RuntimeException: The index 1 is out of range..

We are using `mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre7.jar` library to connect to SQL Server.

What is wrong ?

Comment: Can you show the code that is generating the error

Comment: Peter do you have IBM MobileFIrst Installed ? There is no code except select statement.